# Qpid Erlang Module

Tags: erlang, queue, amqp, message, qpid

I am newbie to erlang but managed to get the ActiveMQ talking to my erlang shell using qpid pronton c library as, which is working well and i am getting messages from queue itself on my erlang shell and vice versa.

```
qpidpn:subscribe("amqp://localhost/topic://xxx").
qpidpn:publish(#{address => "amqp://127.0.0.1/topic://xxx", body => "hello"}).
```

Now, i want to implement the same above stated code using .erl file with some function getting invoked everytime we have new message on the queue and i can take further action of returning the same to origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement gen_server, as seems the messages are coming from some MQ. So, you can get the messages in handle_info. Once there you can do whatever you want to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it all depends on how your subscriber is implemented (is it another process, TCP listener, do you use `gen_event` behaviour, does it decode any data for you .... ).

Since you are using AMQP protocol for communication, you could use [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/erlang-client-user-guide.html) as client.  You would get whole AMQP implementation (with all responses to your broker), and some model for getting messages or subscribing to channels. Code-base is mature, whole project is stable, and most of logic is written for you, so I would strongly recommend using this approach.

The  *"invoked everytime we have new message on the queue"* is somewhat explained in [subscibe to que](https://www.rabbitmq.com/erlang-client-user-guide.html#subscribing) section.

Comment: Thanks mpm but there is a requirement so can not use any other MQ. But tried to work on the code/module which can do the job of reflecting the messages coming from producer to logic server but didn`t got much out of that.

Comment: Than again it would depend on how you are bind C code with Erlang (NIF, driver or Port).  Please give us little more information.  And I could recommend going trough http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/users_guide.html

Comment: And once again, I would suggest using RabbitMQ.  You would be using it only as a client to your ActiveMQ broker, without any change in you AMQP protocol.  It should not look any different from outside of Erlang.

Comment: Thanks mpm, Ok i`ll try to give more detailed information now. First thing is that i can not use any other MQ for now being some requirement only. Secondly, when using iex shell using i managed to use proto c function via qpid-erlang library like iex --erl "-pa ebin -env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ./priv -env LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./priv -s qpidpn start". So, now if i want to make new Elixir/Erlang app suppose i want to use that same command to access the library function from my bash script. That means to use already compiled libraries in Elixir to access proton c library functions.